# getting "415:Media not supported" Error when passing pdf to IBM watson in Salesforce

Tags: pdf, salesforce, ibm-watson, document-conversion

I am planning to integrate the IBM Watson Document Conversion service 
 with Salesforce.

From there I am unable to send my pdf file directly to Watson and I'm getting `Media Type not supported`.

I am also getting this error:

```
{
  "code" : 500 ,
  "error" : "Server Error" ,
  "description" : "2017-07-18T06:02:19-04:00, Error WATSNGWERR-0x0113001c occurred when accessing https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion/api/v1/convert_document?version=2015-12-15&amp;config="{"conversion_target":"answer_units"}", Tran-Id: gateway-dp02-1967135880 - Watson Gateway Error"
}
```

Here is the code I'm using:

```
public class Resume {
  String boundary = '----------------------------741e90d31eff';

  public string id{get;set;}
  public string content{get;set;}
  Transient public Attachment att{set;get;}

  public Resume(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    id=ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    att=new Attachment();
    att=[Select Id,ParentId, Name,body,ContentType From Attachment where ParentId=:id limit 1];
    content=String.valueOf(att.body);

    System.debug('---->' + content);
    String header = '--' + boundary + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="att"; filename="'+att.name+'";\nContent-Type: application/pdf';
    String footer = '--' + boundary + '--';
    String headerEncoded =
    EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
    String bodyEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(att.body);
    Blob bodyBlob = null;
    String last4Bytes =
    bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length() - 4, bodyEncoded.length());
    while (headerEncoded.endsWith('=')){
      header+=' ';
      headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header+'\r\n\r\n'));
    }

    if (last4Bytes.endsWith('==')) {
      last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,2) + '0K';
      bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
      String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
      bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);
    } else if (last4Bytes.endsWith('=')) {
      last4Bytes = last4Bytes.substring(0,3) + 'N';
      bodyEncoded = bodyEncoded.substring(0,bodyEncoded.length()-4) + last4Bytes;
      footer = '\n' + footer;
      String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
      bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);
    } else {
      footer = '\r\n' + footer;
      String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));
      bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);
    }

    String configAsString ='\"conversion_target:answer_units\"';
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);

    String username= 'DOCUMENT-CONVERSION-USERNAME';
    String password= 'DOCUMENT-CONVERSION-PASSWORD';
    request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(blob.valueOf(username + ':' + password)));

    request.setEndpoint('https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion/api/v1/convert_document?version=2015-12-15&config='+configAsString);
    request.setBodyAsBlob(bodyBlob);
    request.setCompressed(true);
    HttpResponse response = h.send(request);
    System.debug(response.getBody());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending the `config` as a query parameter, but it should be in the body.

Here is the curl command that makes what you are trying to do:

```
curl -X POST \
  -u "{username}":"{password}" \
  -F config="{\"conversion_target\":\"answer_units\"}" \
  -F "file=@sample.pdf;type=application/pdf" \
"https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/document-conversion/api/v1/convert_document?version=2015-12-15"
```

I also think there is an error in the way you are creating the body. My team built an SDK to use the Watson APIs in the Salesforce environment. I would suggest you take a look.

If you can't deploy the SDK to your Salesforce organization (It's a lot of code), copy the code from the [IBMWatsonMultipartBody.cls](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/salesforce-sdk/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/IBMWatsonMultipartBody.cls) class. It will help you encode an `Attachment` as base64 so that you can end it to Watson.

---

**UPDATE:** The Document Conversion service was deprecated but the features from that service were enhanced and migrated to the [Discovery service](https://www.ibm.com/watson/services/discovery/)